# Naming a list from an item within an other list

Tags: r

That's probably a very easy one, but I cannot solve my issue. The below code returns an error:

```
person = c("name", "surname")
list(person[1]= "John")

Error : '=' unexpected in "list(person[1]="
```

I would like it to return:

```
$name
[1] "John"
```

Can StackOverflow help me with this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Perhaps the following will be of use:

```
> p <- list("John", "Smith")
> names(p) <- c("name", "surname")
> p
$name
[1] "John"

$surname
[1] "Smith"
```

Comment: I am able to name is using names(p) <- person[1] which was actually my issue. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

Since you seem to be trying to access a list element via a named variable, this might be what you are after. This is pretty much the same as aix's answer, but via a different route.

```
person = c("name", "surname")
```

Create the empty list, which can be inefficient when you grow the list later.

```
x <- list()
```

Now assign values to this list via the "person" values.

```
x[person[1]] <- "John"

x[person[2]] <- "Smith"

x

$name
[1] "John"

$surname
[1] "Smith"
```

I don't think that's really going to help much when you want to keep growing the list, but it might help you see how these things work a little better.